# How would I add an onClickListener to this?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a database that I am displaying through a listview type thing, How would I add on OnClickListener?
Here's the code:

```
public void DisplayRecord(Cursor c) {
    Cursor c1 = DBAdapter.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(c1);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_ITEM };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row,
            c1, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

Or is it even possible?

And how would I sort this list alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I add on OnClickListener?

You want to use an OnItemClickListener with a ListView, or since you are using a ListActivity or ListFragment you can override [`OnListItemClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29).

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something
}
```

> And how would I sort this list alphabetically?

Use the [Order By](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) clause when you query your database in `DBAdapter.getAllRecords();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a onItemClickListener to the listview.

```
yourListVeiw.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
 // id is the clicked item id
     Cursor clickedItem = DBAdapter.getRecord(id);
     // DO what you need to do

}
```

In order to have the list ordered you should implement a getSortedRecords() in your DBAdapter, adding an order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can, but you should set your listener on your ListView, not the adapter that provides its data.
Take a look at `setOnItemClickListener` on [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html)